# Executing SQL LIKE in SQLObject

Tags: sql, orm, sqlobject

Is there a pretty way to execute an SQL statement with a `LIKE` in SQLObject?

This one works, but it's somewhat ugly:

```
    fields = Foo.select("field LIKE '%%%s%%'" % bar)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `sqlobject.sqlbuilder` there is an undocumented class called `LIKE` which can be used amongst other query elements.

For example:

```
from sqlobject.sqlbuilder import LIKE

class Customer(SQLObject):
    name = StringCol()
    ...

# this search is case-dependent
rows = Customer.select(LIKE(Customer.q.name, "%Smith%"))

class ILIKE(LIKE):
    op = 'ILIKE'

# this search is case-independent, works on PostgreSQL, not sure about others
rows = Customer.select(ILIKE(Customer.q.name, '%smith%'))
```

Answer (score 0):

[SqlBuilder](http://www.sqlobject.org/SQLBuilder.html) has a `LIKE` function (and also `startswith` and `endswith` ones that build appropriate `LIKE` clauses).